# adapter.add(event) throws java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-asynctask, android-arrayadapter

I am making an application. I want to add more item after getting the information from server in a asynctask and save with a object defined by me.
This is my code.

EventCheck.java

```
private void put(final Event event){
    if(event!=null){
        events = push(events,event);
        Log.d("no after= ",Integer.toString(event.getNo()));
        if(!firsttime){
            context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    adapter = new Eventlist(context,getEvents());
                    adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
                    list.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });
            firsttime=true;
        }else{
            context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Log.d("no = ",Integer.toString(event.getNo()));
                    Log.d("title = ",event.getTitle());
                    Log.d("description = ",event.getDescription());
                    adapter.add(event);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

adapter.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Eventlist extends ArrayAdapter<Event>{ 
    private final Activity context;
private final Event[] events; 
private final String[] title; 
private final String[] description; 
public Eventlist(Activity context,Event[] events) { 
    super(context, R.layout.list_event, events); 
    this.context = context; 
    this.events = events;
    this.title = new String[events.length];
    this.description = new String[events.length];
    for(int i=0;i<events.length;i++){
        title[i]=events[i].getTitle();
        description[i] = events[i].getDescription();
    }
};
@Override 
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) { 
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater(); 
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_event, null, true); 
    TextView txtContent = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.belisttitle);
    String line = new StringBuilder().append(position+1).append(" .").append(" ").append(title[position]).append(System.getProperty ("line.separator")).toString();
    line = new StringBuilder().append(line).append(description[position]).toString();
    txtContent.setText(line); 
    return rowView;
} 

}
```

It throws the following exception:

```
10-04 16:07:56.855: E/AndroidRuntime(14835): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException 
10-04 16:07:56.855: E/AndroidRuntime(14835):    at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:404) 
10-04 16:07:56.855: E/AndroidRuntime(14835):    at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:425) 
10-04 16:07:56.855: E/AndroidRuntime(14835):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.add(ArrayAdapter.java:179) 
10-04 16:07:56.855: E/AndroidRuntime(14835):    at com.xxx.xxx.Eventcheck$2.run(Eventcheck.java:257) 
10-04 16:07:56.855: E/AndroidRuntime(14835):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
10-04 16:07:56.855: E/AndroidRuntime(14835):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
10-04 16:07:56.855: E/AndroidRuntime(14835):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
10-04 16:07:56.855: E/AndroidRuntime(14835):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5140) 
10-04 16:07:56.855: E/AndroidRuntime(14835):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
10-04 16:07:56.855: E/AndroidRuntime(14835):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
10-04 16:07:56.855: E/AndroidRuntime(14835):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795) 
10-04 16:07:56.855: E/AndroidRuntime(14835):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:611) 
10-04 16:07:56.855: E/AndroidRuntime(14835):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

line 257 is the line adapter.add(event)
I want to ask what wrong is my code?
Anyone can help me to find out the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to ask what wrong is my code?

There's nothing inherently wrong with your code. The short answer is that you're running into a Java-specific quirk. Bear with me:

The source code for the `ArrayAdapter` constructor you're invoking looks like this:

```
public ArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, T[] objects) {
    init(context, textViewResourceId, 0, Arrays.asList(objects));
}
```

Not what happens to the last parameter, the array you supply: it is 'converted' into an `ArrayList` by calling `Arrays.asList(objects)`.

Now, the answer can actually be found by looking at [the documentation for this method call](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29):

> Returns a List of the objects in the specified array. **The size of the List cannot be modified, i.e. adding and removing are unsupported, but the elements can be set. Setting an element modifies the underlying array.**

Basically what happens is that the array you pass in is converted into a *fixed-size* list (if you breakpoint your code at runtime, you should see an `UnmodifiableCollection` instance - note: different from *immutable*). You can't add or remove any items, but only set items (which doesn't change the list size as it replaces an existing item), although the latter operation is not exposed by the `ArrayAdapter` class by default.

The easiest solution is to call the equivalent `ArrayAdapter` constructor that takes an `ArrayList` instead of an array yourself:

```
public ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<T> objects)
```

This would require some minor changes to your current code, but arrays and list are very similar to work with. Also, remember to implement the ViewHolder/RowWrapper pattern in your adapter - plenty of examples out there. Finally, there's not really any benefit to storing the titles & description into separate arrays, and it's kind of in contradiction to the idea of object-oriented programming and encapsulation. Just let the object 'own' those properties and use the getter methods to access them.

**//edit:**

Here's some example code that illustrates the changes to the `ArrayAdapter`, including on how to use the `ViewHolder` pattern. I typed this straight into the browser, so please do mind any types/syntax mistakes.

You'll still have to change your `put()` method slightly so that it works with a list of events instead of an array, but I'll leave that up to you to figure out. There's really a plethora of examples available online to help you out.

```
public class Eventlist extends ArrayAdapter<Event>{

    private static final String LINE_SEPARATOR = System.getProperty ("line.separator");

    public Eventlist(Context context, List<Event> events) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_event, events);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        View rowView = view;
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (rowView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_event, null, true);
            holder.txtContent = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.belisttitle);
            rowView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        }

        Event event = getItem(position);
        StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder(position+1)
            .append(" . ")
            .append(event.getTitle())
            .append(LINE_SEPARATOR)
            .append(event.getDescription());
        holder.txtContent.setText(line);

        return rowView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        private TextView txtContent;
    }

}
```

Comment: As I am new to android, can you give me a guideline and some example code on how to change the code

Comment: @KenCHAN: I've updated the answer with some sample code to help you get started. I would advise you to have a google around for more information, as there's plenty readily available on this subject.

Comment: @KenCHAN: Cool, glad to hear. Don't forget to accept the answer so that others can potentially benefit from it too. Happy coding!